# Why does the line inside method of argument defined method anonymous inner class work?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class, anonymous-methods, anonymous-inner-class

InterfaceInAbstractClass.java

```
public abstract class InterfaceInAbstractClass {

    public interface Inter{

        void interface_method();

    }

    public  void interface_abstract_class_method(Inter in){

    }

}
```

InterfaceInAbstractClassImplementer.java

```
public class InterfaceInAbstractClassImplementer extends InterfaceInAbstractClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){

//      InterfaceInAbstractClass.Inter abcd = new InterfaceInAbstractClass.Inter() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void interface_method() {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              System.out.println("An interface can be implemented ");
//          }
//      };
        System.out.println("An interface can be implemented ");
        InterfaceInAbstractClassImplementer abc = new InterfaceInAbstractClassImplementer();
        abc.interface_abstract_class_method(new Inter() {

            @Override
            public void interface_method() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("An interface can be implemented within a class");
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Why does the System.out.println("An interface can be implemented within a class"); doesn't get printed?

Comment: At first glance, you never call it.

Comment: Because that is not getting called

Comment: You need to call that method. Right now you are just defining the method, not calling it from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small tweak to your implementer class to call the interface function

```
public class InterfaceInAbstractClassImplementer extends InterfaceInAbstractClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("An interface can be implemented ");
        InterfaceInAbstractClassImplementer abc = new InterfaceInAbstractClassImplementer();
        Inter inter = new Inter() {

            @Override
            public void interface_method() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("An interface can be implemented within a class");
            }
        };
        abc.interface_abstract_class_method(inter);
    }

    public void interface_abstract_class_method(Inter inter) {
        inter.interface_method();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
An interface can be implemented
An interface can be implemented within a class
```